# Connecting 2 WiFi Routers in same home network without interconnected by cable [2 ISP wall port]

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

For my query I have checked and tried most of the options, but it doesn't work at all. So, finally, I am posting my query here in hope to have a clear step answer to get the issue resolved.

I have one WiFi router-A which is connected to my home wallPort-A (gateway 192.168.x.x) and I am using it for WiFi access and directly connected to other devices ('cable'). For my other room I wish to add separate router-B to wallPort-B (router-A should not be connected to router-B via cable). As per my understanding both the wallPortsA&B are on same gateway 192.168.x.x.

Please help me to understand the steps of configuring router-B to get connected.

Comment: Your question.appears.vague. What is wallportA and wallportB? What kind of internet connection do you have, and what is the specific roblem ypu are trying to solve? As a rule you cant connect 2 router WAN interfaces into a SOHO Internet connecrion

Comment: Where.do you get 192.168.x.x from? Generallu those are LAN IPs and dont imply anything about the Internet / WAN IP

Comment: Hi @davidgo: thanks for your reply. 
-sorry 192.168.x.x is the gatway from modem. actually it is 192.168.0.1 (i can see it on accessing ipTime primary router connected to wallPort-A); wallport is the port provided in house at multiple locations to access internet in different rooms. so i have 2 ports in my home, one is already connected to primary router, i can use it as wifi point. I wish to add a second router in other room (should be connected to 2nd wallport). what is the configuration i need to set for 2nd router to work it as wifi point as well. please suggest.